# How to forward a TCP port in an Android program

Tags: android, tcp, portforwarding

I have embedded a Jetty server in my Android app. When I use the emulator for testing it works fine because I have forwarded the specified port using `adb forward tcp:1234 tcp:1234`. I want to know how can I forward a port in my Android device so that I can access my server from the browser like I do with the emulator without using any other application.

Comment: Why should you forward the traffic on a real device? You can access directly a listening port on the Android by specifying the ip and the port. Eg: 192.168.1.4:1234. If that was that you want please give more info to help you :)

Comment: No actually that's all i wanted to know,we have to forward port on emulator so i thought we needed to do that for device as well. Thanks

Comment: hey @KhanZeeshan I'm port forwarding in emulator, but what to do in actual devices for that? any Idea? I'm creating a chatting app(over Hotspot).    So I've to make changes in my code? My code is running perfectly on emulator. Please help me.

Comment: answer this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820043/cant-send-message-over-hotspot-using-tcp-connection-android

Comment: @14bce109 please check your question.