# Can't send message over hotspot, using TCP connection. Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm creating an simple app, in which I want to send message over local wifi connection using TCP. So I'm creating hotspot on one device and connect it from other device.

Now, on hosting device, I'm running following server application and on connecting device I'm running client application.

But nothing happens when I press `send` button on client device. My code for both server and client is as following:

Code for server:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

Handler updateConversationHandler;

Thread serverThread = null;

private TextView text;

public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {

            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();

                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Code for client:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket socket;
private String TAG="XXX";

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private String SERVER_IP ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    SERVER_IP = getWifiApIpAddress();

}

public String getWifiApIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en
                .hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            if (intf.getName().contains("wlan")||intf.getName().contains("ap")) {
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr
                        .hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()
                            && (inetAddress.getAddress().length == 4)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
   //     out.flush();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

I'm following [this tutorial.](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) As explained there, It is working fine in android emulators. But doesn't work on actual devices.

So I thought the IP address should be given different on different hotspots. So I've written a method in client code to get server hotspot's IP address and than connect to it. But still nothing happens on pressing `send` button.

So, What am I missing here? Is my method correct? Is there any mistakes in port numbers?

In the tutorial, author is doing something called port forwarding. What about port forwarding for actual devices?

I've searched everywhere for this on Internet but can't find any exact solution or any tutorial explaining this type of application. Please help me!

EDIT:

when I run this in real devices, It is giving `NllPointerException` in clients code, on following line:

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
```

Comment: @greenapps edited my question. But please help me!

Comment: Its also not advisable to cry `Please help me`.

Comment: Its also advisable that If you don't know the answer of the question, don't comment on it. @greenapps

Comment: Does it print a stack trace? Either on the client or the server.

Comment: @immibis yes, on client code, it is giving null pointer exception on line 67. or on line : ` PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);`

Comment: see the edits @immibis

Comment: @14bce109 Then socket is null. Did the thread that was supposed to create the socket print a stack trace?

Comment: @immibis every time when I press `send`, It gives this exception. how to know which thread is printing?

Comment: @14bce109 I'm not sure if you can. But you'll know because the stack trace included ClientThread. It won't be printed when you press send.

Comment: @14bce109 I am telling you that you get a NullPointerException because socket is null. Then I am asking you, why is socket null?

Comment: Thats what I dont know.  @immibis

Comment: @14bce109 What are some possible reasons it would be null?

Comment: @immibis Possible answers: a) Race condition b) swallowed exception upon connection.

Comment: @JimmyB You are not 14bce109.

Comment: Your `getWifiApIpAddress` method will get the IP address *of the device it's running on*, for one thing.

Comment: @immibis I know, but I felt we should give the OP some hints :)

Comment: friends, please tell me whatever you know. Because I'm beginner in this and can't get your hints. please!  @JimmyB

Comment: @14bce109 Ok, then, a) your `ClientThread` does not make any sense; in fact, it may be the cause of problems without providing any benefit, and b) you "swallow" any exceptions which may occur upon connecting instead of handling them appropriately. So, it seems that your client code needs a work-over for you to be able to locate the problem in the first place. And this is independent of any Android-specific problems there may also be.

Comment: But my app works on emulators. @JimmyB

Comment: Maybe, but as I understand it, your question is not about why it does work on the emulator. The question is why it isn't working on a device, and part of the answer will be in the exception's error message which you chose to ignore.

Comment: And the general question may be if it is possible at all to access the local WiFi network from the device which is acting as the access point itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to forward anything on device, just make sure your device is on the same network & use the port you have hard-coded or defined in the settings.

We forward port in emulator because its running on your host machine & we are telling the host to forward traffic coming on that specific port to emulator, since in an actual device you don't need to do that so you just to have to make sure your device is on the same network & correct port is being called.

Comment: "you just to have to make sure your device is on the same network" - That could be the problem. I tend to believe an app cannot use the WiFi network while the device is in access point mode...

Comment: but if one device creates hotspot and another connects on it, than also it is called "on same network" @JimmyB